# Buttons not showing on the NavigationController's toolbar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

This section of my app had a Tab bar with 4 different tabs. Each tab is a table view that shows different buttons on the toolbar. I added a custom toolbar to the views and everything was working fine. However, for design reasons, we are removing the Tab bar; it will be a menu screen instead. Since the Tab bar will no longer be at the bottom of the screen, I figured I can now use the Navigation Controller's toolbar. My problem is that the buttons are never showing in the toolbar!

Here is the code I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;

    // Configure the navigation item with custom buttons
    UIBarButtonItem* flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                      target:nil
                                      action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem* btnClockIn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Clock In"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(clockRespondersIn)];
    UIBarButtonItem* btnClockOut = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                    initWithTitle:@"Clock Out"
                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                    target:self
                                    action:@selector(clockRespondersOut)];
    UIBarButtonItem* btnDismiss = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissResponders)];
    UIBarButtonItem* btnEndJob = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"End Job"
                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                  target:self
                                  action:@selector(endJob)];
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
    self.toolbarItems = @[btnClockOut,flexibleSpace,btnDismiss,flexibleSpace,btnEndJob];
}
```

I tried moving  these statements into viewWillAppear but it didn't help. I don't see what I did wrong. Currently the toolbar shows, but with no buttons. I haven't deleted the custom toolbar, but I'm no longer assigning the buttons to it. If I do assign the buttons, however, they appear like they should in there.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked fine. Could your custom toolbar be covering up the navigation controller's tool bar?

Comment: That is not the case, unfortunately. The custom toolbar is displayed below the last cell in the table, I have tried tables of different length and the behavior stays the same, the custom toolbar will scroll up from under the toolbar. Also, the navigation controller's toolbar is placed on top of the tab bar. I'm thinking maybe the toolbar and tab bar can't coexist. I left the toolbar because I was working on the same view I had, I am going to try starting a fresh view in the storyboard and see what happens. Thanks for testing my code @rdelmar

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are using `UINavigationController`, `self.navigationController` may be nil in `viewDidLoad`. Try to put a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` to that you have a valid navigation controller when the view is being created. You may need to move this to `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Since I am getting the toolbar displayed, I didn't consider a nil pointer. I added an NSLog statement right before calling self.navigationController... and this is the output: _2014-11-10 14:46:07.205 InstantLabor[55516:60b] <UINavigationController: 0x165641a0>_

Answer (score 0):

Since @rdelmar said the code worked when he tested it, I decided to start fresh with a new view controller that wasn't linked at all to the Tab bar controller. It worked right away. I wasn't able to find any information on why this is, but the toolbar from the Navigation controller and the tab bar don't seem to get along.